# How to give back control from Fragment to Activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, kotlin

I have a simple `CalculatorActivity` with consecutively shown Fragments :

1. `InputFragment //requests two input values for calclation`
2. `ResultFragment // show the result of the calculation`

To keep it simple lets assume, I want to calculate the sum of two numbers. 
I start the `CalculatorActivity` which immediately loads the `InputFragment` via:

```
fun replaceFragment(resId : Int, newFragment : Fragment){
    this.supportFragmentManager?.beginTransaction()?.replace(resId, newFragment)?.addToBackStack(null)?.commit()
}
```

`resId` is the resource ID for the container to inflate the fragment in.
`newFragment` is the new Fragment to be inflated. Here in this first step I call in `CalculatorActivity`'s `onCreate()`:

`replaceFragment(R.id.container, InputFragment.getInstance())`

SO FAR this works fine.

But when I enter the required numbers in `InputFragment`, how can I forward the values from `InputFragment` back to the calling `CalculatorActivity`, so that it can continue and inflate the ResultFragment into the very same container to show the result of calculation?

Answer (score 0):

You can always get the enclosing activity from any fragment (by using `getActivity`), then cast it to the proper type and use your own `setValues` method on it. Check out this: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating

Answer (score 0):

You can have the value as a variable in the activity and from the fragment do

```
CalculatorActivity myActivity = (CalculatorActivity)getActivity()
myActivity.setInputValues(fragmentInputValues)
myActivity.doSomethingWithTheValues()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are learning and this is just for fun, then feel free to do the direct cast to activity and access it's public methods. However, I would never do that in real world practice.

Best practice would be to use an interface implementation on the parent activity.

example:
INTERFACE CLASS

```
interface IBaseActivityCallback {
    fun onInputValuesReady(myObjectOfValues: MyObject)
}
```

ACTIVITY CLASS

```
class CalculatorActivity : AppCompatActivity(), IBaseActivityCallback {
     override fun onInputValuesReady(myObjectOfValues: MyObject){
          //handle inflate or usage of values
     }
}
```

FRAGMENT CLASS

```
lateinit var baseActivityCallback: IBaseActivityCallback

override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
     super.onAttach(context)
     //NOTE* wrap in try/catch if context can be something else
     baseActivityCallback = context as IBaseActivityCallback
}

fun someButtonClicked(){
    baseActivityCallback.onInputValuesReady(myObjectToPass)
}
```

I figured I don't need to explain creating an object to hold variables or buttons that were clicked etc.. so I just kept that part generic for you.

Comment: Why you would never do that? Not clean code? Anti-pattern?

Comment: A few reasons. 1) You are coupling the fragment to an activity, at which point the fragment isn't really providing the value of separation any longer. It can only be used with that one activity. 2) getActvity() can return null if you are unattached causing a crash in your code. 3) You are assuming the activity that owns it, is in fact that one type of activity (which in your case is probably ok to assume, but not good practice) 4) You have to cast it every single time you touch it.